# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 with UEFI

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my new Odys Trendbook 12. It came with Win 10 pre-installed.

My problem is that I don't have the option to disable Secure Boot in the UEFI Settings. I created a bootable Ubuntu USB, and when I choose to boot Ubuntu via EFI I get following error message:

```
ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr is missing or corrupted
```

I read that WUBI is incompatible with EFI, but I also read of people who got it to run properly with UEFI and Secure Boot enabled.

Is there a way to create a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu that works with Secure Boot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: I installed 14.04 (which I assume you mean, there is no 14.03) on an UEFI machine without too much trouble.  Are you able to boot the USB into live mode?  Don't even think about using wubi though.

Comment: I have not seen anyone get wubi to work with UEFI. And only a few very advanced users to get any version of wubi past 12.04 to work. But your spec show this: `Intel Bay Trail` which may be a major issue. Do you really have 32 bit UEFI on 64 bit system? https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-14.10-install-asus-x205ta.md or: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2189855&p=12867412#post12867412

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: @OrganicMarble: I'm not able to boot the USB into live mode. That is exactly the problem I have with the other posts about this issue - most were able to install Ubuntu with UEFI, but could not boot afterwards. I can't even install Ubuntu 14.03, nor can I install 15.10.

Comment: I am no expert but I had similar problems with a 64 bit UEFI system refusing to boot off any external media. The boot order setting changes that I made were not persistent. I had to reboot, enter the BIOS, insert the USB, and change the boot order while the USB was present. On subsequent reboots it would again ignore the USB unless I entered the BIOS setup every boot. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Ubuntu are less likely to be UEFI-compatible. I can tell you that I installed Ubuntu 15.10 via bootable USB on my new Win10 computer last night without having to tinker with UEFI settings. You can try changing the boot order in your bios so that the computer will try booting from USB first. It might say "USB Flash" or "USB CD"

Comment: I tried the same with an Ubuntu 15.10 DVD (on a USB flash drive) and got the same Problem, wubildr.mbr missing. My bios doesn't provide the option of changing the boot order either...